# How to show modal if condition is false in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code I am simply uploading a file and then checking the file extension. If the condition is `true` then show an `alert` message and if the condition is `false` then it will open a modal.

What happens now when I select any image is that it shows the `alert` message first and then opens the modal. I don't know why this happens. How can I fix it?

```js
$('#upload_image_student').on("change", function() {
  var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg'];
  if ($.inArray($(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
    alert("Only '.jpeg','.jpg' formats are allowed.");
  } else {
    $("#uploadimageModalStudent").modal("show");
  }
})
```

Comment: What is `#upload_image_student` and how is it changing? I would assume that somehow the "on change" event is being called twice and the conditional is being evaluated differently each time

Comment: It is working fine. See this http://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/dLrmh47e/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "accept" attribute so that you can only select your specified extension. (jpeg, jpg)

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpeg, .jpg"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its a good suggestion, but if the end user is a developer, he can inspect and change the accept value to "*". In that rear scenario this may fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#upload_image_student').on("change", function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var file_type = file['type'];

    const valid_extensions = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg"];

    if($.inArray(file_type, valid_extensions) < 0){
        alert("Only '.jpeg','.jpg' formats are allowed.");
    }
    else{
        //alert("Valid");
        $("#uploadimageModalStudent").modal("show");
    }
})
```

Can you try with this code.